# Trouble reading data from sql database using java

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, database, javafx

I am trying to read data from my ORDER table in my sql database but every time I try I get the error:

```
run-single:
```

Database connected

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "ORDER" at line 1, column 15.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at glassfish.Neasdasda.initializeDB1(Neasdasda.java:1495)
    at glassfish.Neasdasda.order(Neasdasda.java:1463)
    at glassfish.Neasdasda$3.handle(Neasdasda.java:103)
    at glassfish.Neasdasda$3.handle(Neasdasda.java:99)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Syntax error: Encountered "ORDER" at line 1, column 15.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatementX(Unknown Source)
    ... 52 more
```

I have no problem connecting to the database and there isn't a problem with the query statement I am using as I have used the same query statement to read from different tables already.

```
    public void order(Stage currentScreen2){


        GridPane pane2 = new GridPane();
        Button btShowDetails = new Button("Show Details");
        pane2.add(btShowDetails, 1, 4);
        pane2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pane2.setPadding(new Insets(40.5,42.5,43.5,40.5));
        pane2.setHgap(15.5);
        pane2.setVgap(20.5);


            Scene scene5 = new Scene(pane2, 1200, 400);




        currentScreen2.setTitle("Employees");
        currentScreen2.setScene(scene5);
        currentScreen2.show();
        initializeDB();


  //@Override // Override the start method in the Application class

        initializeDB2();



    hBox1.getChildren().addAll(new Label("ID"), tfid, btShowDetails);


    vBox1.getChildren().addAll(hBox1, lblordid, lblcustid, lblprice, lbldescrip, lblpay);

    tfid.setPrefColumnCount(6);
    //Set event listener 
    btShowDetails.setOnAction(e -> showDetail());

    // Create a scene and place it in the stage

  }

  private void initializeDB2() {
    try {
          // Establish a connection
      Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection
        //Test1 is the name of the database you created
        ("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/SandwichDB");
      System.out.println("Database connected");
        //Next we want to write the SQL statement we want to run. Note that the fields such as firstName and lastName are named the same as in the Table. The Question mark is the input we will later put in
      String queryString = "SELECT * FROM ORDER WHERE ORDERID = ?";

      // Create a statement
//Set the prepared Statement to run the queryString we previously set up
      preparedStatementss = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private void showDetail() {
    //This takes the number entered in the text field and puts it into a string called id
    String id = tfid.getText();
    try {
    //Next we want to replace the ? in the previous query with the input 
    //The 1 is notifying we want to replace the first ?
      preparedStatementss.setString(1, id);
      ResultSet rset = preparedStatementss.executeQuery();
    //Now it goes through each field and assigns them to a variable 
      if (rset.next()) {
        String ordered = rset.getString(1);
        String custard = rset.getString(2);
        String pricerd = rset.getString(3);
        String descripered = rset.getString(4);
        String payered = rset.getString(5);

        // Display result in a label
        lblordid.setText("Order ID: " + ordered);
        lblcustid.setText("Customer ID: " + custard);
        lblprice.setText("Price: " + pricerd);
        lbldescrip.setText("Description: " + descripered);
        lblpay.setText("Payment Type: " + payered);
      } else {
        lblordid.setText("Not found");
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
                }




}
```

Here is the code I am using to attempt to read from the database. Please keep in mind that it reads it from all other tables except this one, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Barry can you show your query here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ORDER is part of a key word (e.g. `ORDER BY`), you'll need to quote the table name. Change

```
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM ORDER WHERE ORDERID = ?";
```

to

```
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM `ORDER` WHERE ORDERID = ?";
```